# How to perform Subversion's switch in PHPStorm

Tags: php, svn, ide, phpstorm

Is it possible to make a `switch` Subversion command from interface of PHPStrom? I'm searching for it and searching and can't find it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Unsure of the version of PHP Storm you're using but...

Right click your project, Subversion > Update Directory...

You must hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> if you don't see the ellipses because you unchecked the "Display options dialog when these commands are invoked" option (see comments below).

Comment: Newest EAP Version. But I don't want to `update` my working copy. I want to switch working copy to another branch.

Comment: Yep, poor naming on PHPStorm's part, the update directory can perform a switch too...

Comment: Ohhh. I checked that I don't want to show that update window on next updates and forgot, that was such thing. That's why I didn't see switch options. Thanks! :)

Comment: 2singles: where can i revert that flag to show this window again?

Comment: @Skay: Settings -> Version Control (Project settings) -> Confirmation and there you will have: "Display options dialog when these commands are invoked" box with "Update" and "Checkout".

Comment: if you see `Update Directory` without the ellipses (...) you need to change your settings as @singles directs.

Comment: Does anyone know what happens to shelved changes when you switch branch like this?

Comment: a few years later ... @PeterBagnall you can still unshelve them ... it works like a patch/merge

Answer (score 1):

If you set "Don't show this window again" checkbox in "Update" dialog you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when clicking "VCS Update" button or hold it when selecting "Update Directory" to be able to switch branches.